# Launchd Shell Script Execution Fails

Tags: shell, launchd

I'm trying to use Launchd to run the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

## wait for sunset, touch file

NIGHTTIME='/Users/mnewman/Documents/webcam/nighttime.txt'

sunwait civ down  14.98N 102.09E
touch "$NIGHTTIME"
```

"sunwait" is an executable which runs in the background and waits for sunset/sunrise and then quits. In this case I'm setting it to wait until civilian twilight sunset at my geographic location.

If I run this script from the command line it works fine. If I run it using Launchd, the touch command runs before sunwait finishes. I need for sunwait to finish before executing the next line. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you see sunwait still in the process table? That is to say, how do you know that `touch` runs before `sunwait` returns, rather than `sunwait` failing and exiting early in this case?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest putting `exec >/tmp/wait-for-night.log 2>&1; set -x` at the beginning of your script and looking at the contents of `/tmp/wait-for-night.log` after reproducing this behavior.

Comment: (As an aside -- I'd encourage you to use lowercase names for variables scoped within your script, such as `NIGHTTIME`; all-uppercase names are, by convention, reserved for environment variables and builtins, such that using lowercase names for shell variables prevents unintentional conflicts).

Answer (score 1):

The most likely case here is that you have `sunwait` installed in a location that isn't in launchd's `PATH`. The solution is simply to specify the `PATH` to use in your script -- and, as a safety measure, to tell your script to not create the file if `sunwait` fails.

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin
nighttime=/Users/mnewman/Documents/webcam/nighttime.txt

sunwait civ down  14.98N 102.09E || exit
touch "$nighttime"
```

Changing the shebang line to `#!/bin/sh -e` would also have the effect of causing the script to bail early if `sunwait` failed to run, though using `set -e` has significant caveats (documented in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)).